# AWS GLUE child node execution order of same level

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

If two child nodes has same parent node in AWS GLUE. How to set the priority of execution of specific child node.

For instances AWS GLUE job has three nodes. Node A is parent of child node B and child node C. In this case how to configure child node C will execute first.
Is there any ways please suggest.

Comment: I'm not clear with your notion of child node, are you using Glue workflow with a job A transitioning to job B and C running in parallel?